# Installation of android ADT in myeclipse

Tags: android

I am using Myeclipse 6.0.1. I am trying to configure it for android application development. While trying to install the android ADT I am getting the following error message:

```
Requested operation cannot be performed because it would invalidate the current configuration. See details for more information.
  Android Development Tools (20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.6.0)", or later version.
  Android DDMS (20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires plug-in 
"org.eclipse.ui (3.6.2)", or later version.
  Android Hierarchy Viewer (20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires plug-in 
"org.eclipse.ui (3.6.2)", or later version.
  Android Traceview (20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires plug-in 
"org.eclipse.ui (3.6.2)", or later version.
  Android Native Development Tools (20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires feature "org.eclipse.cdt".
```

I have downloaded the org.eclipse.core.runtime (3.6.0) in zip file and placed it in the eclipse plugin directory. Again tried to do the same thing... but the error message was same.

Please help me to install android ADT in eclipse

Comment: why not install the normal distro of eclipse?!

Answer (score 2):

try to install Adt on java eclipse for EE developer and use the latest versions of eclipse and adt and sdk , that is my advice

Comment: Is it not possible to install the android ADT on the same version of Myeclipse 6.0.1

Comment: MyEclipse 6.0.1 is a very old release. You'd probably have better luck with the latest release of MyEclipse (10.6), which is based on eclipse Indigo. Or use an eclipse package, as forsubhi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the ADT that you are installing is of earlier(less) or equal version than SDK you have installed.
Installing ADT of higher version than SDK will give you error.

Comment: while installing android ADT it is not asking for version

Comment: @Vikas :Download the latest version of eclipse-JUNO and install SDK on it and then make sure that the ADT you install is of lower version or equal to SDK.
Your problem is probably because you are using  a very old version of eclipse.

Comment: @Vikas:Please accept the answers if you are satisfied with it by clicking on the tick-mark at the left side of answer,so that your question gets closed.Thanx.